# How to switch from front to back camera on naxa 9" Core tablet

Tags: applications

When taking a picture oh a Naxa 9" Core tablet, it will only display the front camera, not the back camera. I have touched the Camera Icon on the screen but it just takes a picture instead of switching the camera to the back camera like the instructions in the manual says.  Is there a quick fix for this or do I need to return the item to the store.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your Camera application
2. Swipe in from the left of the screen to reveal the camera and
   video icons.